# Why must the size of TCP/IP headers be multiple of 32 bit?

Tags: networking, tcp, network-programming, ip

I've searched, but most books just say that there's padding to make the header a multiple of 32 bit. Why must it be a multiple of 32 bit?

Comment: I think this link may help you: http://www.sans.org/security-resources/tcpip.pdf

Comment: So that the payload will start on a 32-bit boundary, from where it can be copied more efficiently by hardware.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason is [memory alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

I'll start off with an analogy - imagine a huge filing room with 1000 filing drawers. The room consists of 100 individual cabinets, with 10 drawers each. Each drawer can hold a single sheet of paper, and your secretary (which processes the data in the drawers) can handle 10 sheets of data at a time.

It's simpler and more efficient to tell the secretary "go process cabinet #83" compared to "go process drawers 5-10 in cabinet 12 and drawers 1-5 in cabinet 13" although the amount of data being processed is the same.

It's roughly the same with CPUs. CPUs (secretaries) don't normally work on one byte (drawer) at a time. Instead, they work on [words](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_%28computer_architecture%29) (multiple drawers) which can be up to 512 bits long (64 bytes) because working on an entire word at a time is usually much more efficient than working on smaller chunks of data. Typical word lengths for modern CPUs is 32 or 64 bit, with 64 bit CPUs becoming widespread only in the last 10 or so years.

Since a CPU can read an entire memory row (filing cabinet) in a single operation, accessing the ten drawers at address 100-109 takes less time than accessing the ten drawers whose address is 105-114 since the former reside in two different cabinets and therefore require two separate memory accesses. So it's faster to access any 10 consecutive drawers whose address starts with a multiple of ten. For CPUs, that translates to faster access to addresses that are multiples of 32 or 64 bits.